# Multiple spaces in a for /f loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to separate a string based on spaces, but only after the first space. However, the second string returns only one word.

The code I'm currently using is this:

```
@echo off
set string=alone these are together
for /f "tokens=1 " %%g IN ("%string%") do set first=%%g
for /f "tokens=2*" %%g IN ("%string%") do set second=%%g
echo %first%
echo %second%
pause
```

Right now, my output is `alone` `these`, but I want `alone` `these are together`.

Am I setting the variable wrong, or is my sytax on the token option incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is its own token in the token list, so `"tokens=2*" %%g` puts the second token in `%string%` in `%%g` and everything after it in `%%h`.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%g IN ("%string%") do (
    set "first=%%g"
    set "second=%%h"
)
```

will put the first the first token in `%first%` and everything else in `%second%`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Although my script needs a lot of these, so I found it easier to combine the 3 lines into one `for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%string%") do (set "first=%%a" & set "second=%%b")`